# Joining string based on condition

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have three properties of an object and I want to append to a string based on which property is selected and that includes combinations as well. I want efficient solution that looks neat. The properties are of type boolean. `Appointment.IsDocumentAvailable, Appointment.IsCartChecked, Appointment.IsFinal` based on these values, I would like to append corresponding value to a string.

For example

`string tempString;`

`if(Appointment.IsDocumentAvailable) tempString = 'Bzd';`

`if(Appointment.IsCartChecked) tempString = 'Wkb';`

`if(Appointment.IsFinal) tempString = 'Alles';`

And now the all the possible combinations. Is there a neater way, than several combinations of if-else, to do it?

Comment: How would you join two strings without conditions? This is the problem you should solve first! :-)

Comment: Using a StringBuilder and its Append method requires only three ifs

Comment: are you looking for `+=`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could use:

```
System.Text.StringBuilder builder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

builder.Append(Appointment.IsDocumentAvailable ? "Bzd" : "");
builder.Append(Appointment.IsCartChecked ? "Wkb" : "");
builder.Append(Appointment.IsFinal ? "Alles" : "");

var tempString = builder.ToString();
```

Comment: Why do you add an empty string if condition is false? It looks pointless. There is also `string.Empty` static field, which can be used instead of `""`

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [`StringBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=netframework-4.8) class for that, with any numbers of combinations and finally get a result string:

```cs
var builder = new StringBuilder();
if (Appointment.IsDocumentAvailable)
    builder.Append("Bzd");
if (Appointment.IsCartChecked)  
    builder.Append("Wkb");
if (Appointment.IsFinal) 
    builder.Append("Alles");
...
var tempString = builder.ToString();
```

Since regular [`string` in C# is immutable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=netcore-3.1#remarks), `StringBuilder` is recommended to create a strings which can be dynamically changed. Don't forget to add `using System.Text;` in the using directives.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a [StringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=netframework-4.8) [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods), which will accept a predicate and if it's true, will add the supplied text.

```
public static class StringBuilderExtensions
{
    public static void AppendPredicate(this StringBuilder stringBuilder, Func<bool> func, string text)
    {
        if (func())
        {
            stringBuilder.Append(text);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var tempString =  new StringBuilder();
tempString.AppendPredicate(() => Appointment.IsDocumentAvailable, "Bzd");
tempString.AppendPredicate(() => Appointment.IsCartChecked, "Wkb");
tempString.AppendPredicate(() => Appointment.IsFinal, "Alles");
Console.WriteLine(tempString); // or tempString.ToString()
```